# showing the splash screen image and loading/showing the interstitial ad

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I'm looking to integrate an interstitial Ad in my app before home screen
how can I do this?
here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class HomeMain extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_main);

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    //set the ad unit ID
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

    //Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });
}

private void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

thanks